# Bigquery mkdef allow quoted newlines option

Tags: google-bigquery

What's the parameter to allow quoted newlines when using the cli bq mkdef command?  I see the options in the ui when creating a csv external table but allow_quoted_newlines isnt working for mkdef.

Comment: Based on my understanding, the `bq mkdef` command does not support `allow_quoted_newlines`. Have you tried with the BigQuery UI console?